# Where can I find the first proof of $\int_0^1H_xdx=\gamma$

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, euler-mascheroni-constant

We can prove $$\int_0^1H_xdx=\gamma$$ as such:$$\int_0^1H_xdx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right)\right)=\gamma$$ where $H_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)$ is the generalization of the harmonic numbers. But I don't know where I can find a reference for this identity. When was it first made? I found this on a Wikipedia page for a list of integrals of Euler's constant without citation. It's the second to last one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Integrals). Another proof of this formula is also accepted.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: You may improve your question by defining all functions involved. $H_x$ might be a standard but it does not hurt to make your posting self-contained, specially since it is a short question.

Comment: I agree but that doesn't justify that they are duplicates.